# On creation of folder in a specified folder create sub folders in the new folder

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, automator

I'm new to AppleScript and Automator. I have explored the different threads at Apple but unable to find something useful.

Well, my problem is that I have a folder i.e "work" I have applied folder action on it. On creation of new folder at "work" i.e "abc" I want to create three new folders in "abc". Check out my code

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
  tell application Finder
    repeat with this_item in added_items
        make new folder at this_item with properties {name:"Main"}
        make new folder at this_item with properties {name:"Lower"}
        make new folder at this_item with properties {name:"Upper"}
   end repeat
  end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see wrong in your *code* is `tell application Finder`, as `Finder` in this case is a *variable*, since it's not double-quoted.  It should be: `tell application "Finder"`

That said, you have as Tags, *macos*, *mac*, *applescript* and *automator* and did not state in the OP where and how you've applied the *code* to the *target folder*, `this_folder`, as a **Folder Action**.  In other words, if you've created the **Folder Action** in **Automator** and have just that *code* as the *code* in a **Run AppleScript** *action*, even with the double-quotes around **Finder**, it will fail. That coding structure is only valid as an **AppleScript .scpt** *file* assigned to a **Folder Action** using **Folder Actions Setup...** on the **Services** section of the *contact menu* in **Finder**.

The following *example code* is how I'd write it as an **AppleScript .scpt** *file* assigned to a **Folder Action** using **Folder Actions Setup...** on the **Services** section of the *contact menu* in **Finder**.

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    try
        tell application "Finder"
            repeat with this_item in added_items
                if (class in (get properties of this_item) as string) is "«class cfol»" then
                    make new folder at this_item with properties {name:"Main"}
                    make new folder at this_item with properties {name:"Lower"}
                    make new folder at this_item with properties {name:"Upper"}
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
    end try
end adding folder items to
```

Note that even though by using the `try` *statement*, it should eat any errors, nonetheless, I've also added an `if` *statement* to make sure the *item* being acted upon is a *folder*, not a *file*. Note that while the `if` *statement* is not absolutely necessary, nonetheless, it's a more proper way to write *code* in my opinion, however, it could be left out if *you* want.

User's **AppleScript .scpt** *files* for **Folder Actions** should be saved to, e.g.:

```
/Users/me/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts/filename.scpt
```

---

If you are creating the **Folder Action** via **Automator**, then in the **Run AppleScript** *action* use the following *example* code_:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    try
        tell application "Finder"
            repeat with this_item in input
                if (class in (get properties of this_item) as string) is "folder" then
                    make new folder at this_item with properties {name:"Main"}
                    make new folder at this_item with properties {name:"Lower"}
                    make new folder at this_item with properties {name:"Upper"}
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
    end try
end run
```

---

Note that I have tested both *example code blocks* under the conditions stated above and it works as coded.

Comment: i have a folder in documents named "workdir" i applied folder action on it and in the workflow dragged the Run AppleScript utility copied your code and saved it but it is not working when creating a new folder in "workdir"